# Unable to administer WSS 3.0 using SQL Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, log-files, sharepoint-services

I have a WSS 3.0 running on Server 2008 R1.  The log files have grown to almost 15GB and need to be compressed/purged as we are running out of space on the hard drive.  I have connected to the database "\.\pipe\mssql$microsoft##ssee\sql\query" using SQL Studio Express, however I get the following error when right-clicking on the SharePoint_Config database and selecting Properties:

> ===================================
>
> Property Owner is not available for Database
>   '[SharePoint_Config_29c26fca-17b8-48c1-9704-b869932abcb6]'. This
>   property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due
>   to insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.5000.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.PropertyCannotBeRetrievedExceptionText&EvtID=Owner&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.HandleNullValue(Int32
>   index)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.GetValueWithNullReplacement(String
>   propertyName, Boolean throwOnNullValue)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.get_Owner()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.DatabasePrototype.DatabaseData..ctor(CDataContainer
>   context, String databaseName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.DatabasePrototype.LoadDefinition(String
>   newName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.DatabasePrototype..ctor(CDataContainer
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DBPropSheet..ctor(CDataContainer
>   context)

I am trying to follow the procedure as explained here: http://luka.manojlovic.net/2008/06/15/reduce-sharepoint-services-30-logldf-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before on Windows Small Business Server 2008 where the SharePoint_Config database owner was NULL. I don't know how or why it happens, but you can see if it's the case in your situation using [`sp_helpdb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178568.aspx). If you find it is you can use [`sp_changedbowner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630.aspx) to set the owner. On the SharePoint_Config database setting the owner to `sa` will work fine.

Basically, you'd connect to the database with SSMS and run a query like:

```
USE [SharePoint_Config_29c26fca-17b8-48c1-9704-b869932abcb6]
GO
EXEC sp_changedbowner ‘sa’
GO
```

That'll set the owner.

Comment: That was exactly what the problem was!  Executing sp_changedbowner fixed it right away.  Thank you :)